How can I obtain a 360 degree image from 3 non overlapping 120 degree fov images?
I am trying to stitch or project three images from three 120 degree FoV cameras that have been aligned to perfectly cover a 360 degree FoV. They have no overlap so the common stitching techniques using opencv's Stitcher class will not work as relies on overlapping and detecting matching orb points between the images. Basic concatenation does not work either as they need to be warped or projected on to a cylinder in order to get the correct 360 degree image. I am using the CARLA Simulator and Python library.
Camera setup code:
def create_camera_setup(world, blueprint_library, vehicle):
    # Create a camera blueprint
    camera_bp = blueprint_library.find('sensor.camera.rgb')
    camera_bp.set_attribute('fov', '120')
    camera_bp.set_attribute('image_size_x', '1024')
    camera_bp.set_attribute('image_size_y', '728')

    # Set up forward-facing cameras
    camera_left = spawn_camera(world, camera_bp, vehicle, carla.Transform(
        carla.Location(x=0.2, y=-0.3, z=1.3),  
        carla.Rotation(pitch=0, yaw=-60, roll=0)
    ))
    camera_right = spawn_camera(world, camera_bp, vehicle, carla.Transform(
        carla.Location(x=0.2, y=0.3, z=1.3), 
        carla.Rotation(pitch=0, yaw=60, roll=0)
    ))

    # Set up rear-facing camera
    camera_rear = spawn_camera(world, camera_bp, vehicle, carla.Transform(
        carla.Location(x=0.2, y=0, z=1.3),
        carla.Rotation(pitch=0, yaw=180, roll=0)
    ))

    # Set up IMU
    imu_bp = blueprint_library.find('sensor.other.imu')
    imu = world.spawn_actor(imu_bp, carla.Transform(carla.Location(x=1.6, y=0, z=1.7)), attach_to=vehicle)

    # Set up GPS
    gps_bp = blueprint_library.find('sensor.other.gnss')
    gps = world.spawn_actor(gps_bp, carla.Transform(carla.Location(x=1.6, y=0, z=1.7)), attach_to=vehicle)

    return {
        'camera_left': camera_left,
        'camera_right': camera_right,
        'camera_rear': camera_rear,
        'imu': imu,
        'gps': gps
    }

Current simple concatenation of the images:
def create_360_view(camera_left, camera_right, camera_rear):
    left_img = camera_left.get_data()
    right_img = camera_right.get_data()
    rear_img = camera_rear.get_data()

    combined_img = np.concatenate((left_img, right_img, rear_img), axis=1)
    return combined_img

def display_image(display, image):
    surface = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(image.swapaxes(0, 1))
    display.blit(surface, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

Camera Aspects: 120 degree fov, 1024x728
Resulting image:
https://ibb.co/FnFhBcp
I have tried some transformation work as seen below but the images have gaps between them when projected:
def create_360_view(camera_left, camera_right, camera_rear):
    left_img = camera_left.get_data()
    right_img = camera_right.get_data()
    rear_img = camera_rear.get_data()

    height, width = left_img.shape[:2]

    panorama_width = width * 3
    panorama = np.zeros((height, panorama_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    place_image_cylindrical(panorama, left_img, 0, width)
    place_image_cylindrical(panorama, right_img, width, width)
    place_image_cylindrical(panorama, rear_img, 2*width, width)

    return panorama

def place_image_cylindrical(panorama, img, start_x, width):
    height, img_width = img.shape[:2]
    cylinder_radius = width / (2 * np.pi / 3)  # 120 degrees = 2π/3 radians
    
    theta = np.linspace(-np.pi/3, np.pi/3, width)
    h = np.arange(height) - height // 2
    theta, h = np.meshgrid(theta, h)
    
    x = np.round(cylinder_radius * np.tan(theta) + img_width / 2).astype(int)
    y = np.round(h * np.cos(theta) + height / 2).astype(int)
    
    mask = (x >= 0) & (x < img_width) & (y >= 0) & (y < height)
    
    panorama_x = np.round(theta * width / (2*np.pi/3) + start_x).astype(int)
    panorama_y = h + height // 2
    
    valid_mask = mask & (panorama_x >= 0) & (panorama_x < panorama.shape[1]) & (panorama_y >= 0) & (panorama_y < panorama.shape[0])
    
    panorama[panorama_y[valid_mask], panorama_x[valid_mask]] = img[y[valid_mask], x[valid_mask]]

Resulting image:
https://ibb.co/Mk2FXtV

can you confirm that your 3072x728 picture is three cameras having exactly 120 degrees horizontal field of view each? -- this is almost like mapping onto a skybox, except that has four views of 90 degrees. I have old code... -- settle on a projection type for the result. equirectangular is popular. now DIY the sampling. for each pixel in the result, map it onto a sphere, and from there onto one of the three perspectives. sample the image. set the resulting pixel. you'll only have to understand how equirect and perspective projections work, and how to transform from one to the other.

@ChristophRackwitz I have edited the question to show the setup code for the cameras. Each are 120 degree fov for sure with each producing a 1024x728 image so the resulting 360 should be the original height and 3x the width (3072x728). I will look into the equirectangular projection and sphere mapping. Thanks

and what kind of answer are you looking for? you are using python, so I'll assume numpy is fine. restrictions on other libraries?

You haven't quite got 120 degree fields of view or exact rotation around the camera's centre - a part of the steering wheel is missing on the RHS in the front forwards view. It looks like a rendered image why don't you just render it again? I presume you want something that looks vaguely continuous with curves where straight lines would have been and without the sharp angular transitions between frames. It would have been easier to lose/hide the errors on the back window rather than on the main windscreen.

@ChristophRackwitz yes I am using python. I currently have attempted a few different attempts with PIL, opencv, and numpy. So I do not necessarily have restrictions on libraries but am trying to stick to ones that only require pip and not custom installation

@MartinBrown This isn't necessarily "rendered". I am running a simulation inside CARLA and trying to extract images from their Camera object. As seen in my edit, the Camera objects are setup for 120 degree fov with a capture size of 1024x728. I have placed these cameras .6 units apart in the horizontal plane and adjusted the yaw in order to try and match them up perfectly. I may need to work on the alignment, but that is not the issue at hand currently as I know how to make those movements. What I am looking for is a way to make a 360 degree image which can be later processed for obj detection

why did you translate the cameras? they need to have the same center. translation ruins the pictures. -- why not render four views, producing the sides of a cubemap? that's a lot more common, and you're likely to find existing shaders that'll do what you want, based on the faces of a cubemap -- maybe i'll unearth my old code and get it working on your picture. can't guarantee anything. especially not a flawless result, given what @MartinBrown just said about the edges of the views not lining up properly.

@ChristophRackwitz I translated the cameras because this is simulating an actual device with 3 distinct cameras (something similar to the comma3x). It isn't a single camera rotating about an axis. Once I get the projection and mapping working, the next step is to adjust the translations in order to perfect the alignment. The library for the Camera object and image extraction is CARLA and can be found here: carla python api docs.

none of that explains why you can't just put all three cameras at the same translation. I'll let that be for now.

@ChristophRackwitz because these are in a single dashcam like package and will be used simultaneously, thus cannot be physically on top of one another. Looking at my code, I realize I have them rather far away at 60cm. So when fixing the translation to be more realistic 6cm apart, the resulting image has much better alignment as seen here

A little more tinkering and splitting the rear image in half to better see the image as I want here is the resulting output, I am less worried about poor seams within the vehicle and more concerned with the transitions between objects outside of the vehicle which seem fairly good. Most recent output

ah, the construction will be implemented in the real world. fair.
